# iOS tableview setEditing reduce the content size from left and right

Tags: ios, uitableview

If I enable the property `setEditing:animated:` for any `tableview` cell, `contentView` size is getting decreased from left and right. Below image, you can see blue color is `contentView` of cell. I am also forcing the right side label and `delete` button on right side of contentview by setting the constraint constant property of trailing. But by doing this I am only able to click button which is coming on content view. Outside contentView part of button is not clickable

[image]

How do I make the button (delete) fully clickable which is outside 'contentView' in cell?

Comment: All of your cell subviews should be added to the cell's `contentView`, not the cell itself. And you any constraints should be relative to the `contentView`.

Comment: @rmaddy cell subview is already added to cell's contentView and constraints is relative to the contentView. What should i do

Comment: Something must be setup incorrectly. Otherwise your subviews would stay inside the content view no matter what size the content view is.

Comment: @rmaddy.. for testing, I added a custom cell with similar label and button without any constraint. and enabled the property setEditing:animated. but same thing is happening even without constraints